# Static method in products created by factory

Tags: java, static, factory

I have a factory that creates different types of products:

```
public class Factory {
    public Product createProduct(String type) {
        if(type.equals("Product1")) {
            return new Product1();
        }
        else if(type.equals("Product2")) {
            return new Product2();
        }
    }
}
```

The product classes look like this:

```
public abstract class Product {
    public static doSomething() {
        //...
    }
}

public class Product1 extends Product {
    //...
}

public class Product2 extends Product {
    //...
}
```

Depending on a String value I'd like to call `doSomething()` on the corresponding class. How can I call `doSomething()` on the corresponding class without creating an instance of it?
Is there a better way than creating if-else statements as shown below?

```
if(type.equals("Product1")) {
    //call doSomething() on Product1 class
}
else if(type.equals("Product2")) {
    //call doSomething() on Product2 class
}
```

Comment: _Why_ is `doSomething()` static? The entire purpose of polymorphism is to be able to change behavior in subclasses.

Comment: Why do you want to call a static method based on an instance of the class? The idea of a static method is that it is not instance specific.

Comment: `doSomething()` is static, because it fetches data from an API that returns every product. Instead of an instance of the Product class, it returns a list of names of existing products.

Comment: It would be helpful to insert a return type in the `public static doSomething()` declaration. Then, you don’t need to write another comment telling us what this method returns. And the compiler mandates it anyway. So far you have a `static` method `doSomething()` in the class `Product` and ask how to invoke it. Well, the answer is `Product.doSomething();` but maybe you’re asking the wrong question?

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to use reflection:

```
Factory factory = new Factory();

Product product = factory.createProduct("Product1");

try{
    
    //get the method `doSomething` from product reference.
    Method doSomethingMethod = product.getClass().getMethod("doSomething");

    //invoke the method from product reference
    doSomethingMethod.invoke(product);

catch(Exception e){ 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

But my question is why you don't directly call `Product.doSomething()`?

Because this method is `static` that means you can't override it in subclasses.

Comment: +1 for questioning the intent. There is no reason to seek the static method based on an instance. The whole purpose of static methods is that it should apply to all instances of the class.

Comment: Then, what problem does the invocation by Reflection solve?

Comment: @Holger `How can I call doSomething()...` This is what is asked in question. But I'm not sure what exactly OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: “without creating an instance of it”. You have created an instance, so you’re not answering the question literally. Besides that, instead of `product.getClass().getMethod("doSomething") .invoke(product)` you can simply do `product.doSomething()`, to the same effect. And you already know that it’s still the same as `Product.doSomething()`, so it’s not clear why you are suggesting Reflection. It does neither, answer the question literally, nor does it seem to solve any other problem.

Comment: You are right, except `product.doSomething()` you can't call statics from instances :)

Comment: Of course you can. Did you try it? As [the specification says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.1-100-C), “*If form is `ExpressionName . [TypeArguments] Identifier`, then: - If the invocation mode is `static`, then there is no target reference. The `ExpressionName` is evaluated, but the result is then discarded.*” Just the same as with the reflective invocation, `product` is evaluated and then ignored. Reasonable IDEs will give you a warning though.

Comment: Looks like this feature is on later versions. I have tried with jdk10 and don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call doSomething on your subclasses without instantiating them, I mean you can but there will be no difference between product1 and product2 because you are you are going to call the doSomething of the abstract class product because you can't override a static method, you could make the doSomething method of product non-static so that you could override it and have different implementation of it in different subclasses like you want without even checking the type, but then you'd have to instantiate the objects on which you want to call the method, so I suggest not defining the doSomething method in product and just add a "personal" static one to each subclass, as so that you could still assign every product subclass to a product variable like a list and call the method, but then again it would make no sense because why wanting to make the method static so that you don't have to instantiate stuff and then still instantiate them on a list?  And why having a factory class whose purpose is exactly to instantiate objects if you want to call doSomething without instantiating? Confusing. it'd be easier if you removed the factory or made doSomething non-static and finally instantiate stuff.  I'm tired of writing instantiate, ugh, ugly and complicated word.

Comment: I haven't added the full implementation of the classes, but the factory is needed because I need instances of those classes. But you are right, `doSomething()` cannot be static in this context, as I want it to use class-specific data.